# Tab completion not working in zsh with custom script to change iTerm profile

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, macos-ventura

I am basically following this (rather dated) [gist by Hector Leiva](https://github.com/hectorleiva/iterm2-ssh-color-scheme) because I want my iTerm color scheme to change when I ssh to specific hosts.

I am using ZSH and `oh-my-zsh`.

Everything is working (i.e. the iTerm profile changes when I ssh) *except tab completion*.

When I hit `<tab>` after typing `ssh`, zsh offers file/folder names for completion instead of hosts. Without the additional function tab completion for ssh *is working as desired*.

The only "special thing" I know I have in my `.zshrc` is a `zstyle` definition to use an additional `known-hosts` file for completion. However, I have tried with this removed as well to no avail.

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:hosts' known-hosts-files /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts <some_path>/ssh-hostkeys/more_known_hosts
```

It seems that the call to `compdef` is not doing the desired magic?

```
compdef _ssh tabc=ssh
```

---

Ps.: I cannot use iTerm2's built in automatic profile switching (in "Profiles" > "Advanced") because I cannot install Shell integration everywhere.